# Write chinese notes into xcode sdk frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

I get this message showing I do not have permission.

Comment: You can't modify the system header files.

Comment: In short,do not do that

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify files that belongs to the sdk in any language.

Comment: Technically you can modify them (by simply pressing the Unlock button), but the SDK would have to be copied to the device the app is running on for the changes to take place.